# JavaScript let if else statement args

Tags: javascript, let

I'm trying to define a let in JavaScript so that if there's no `arg[2]`, then it will just use `arg[1]`, but if there is `arg[1]` and `arg[2]` it will use them both.

```
ie. command: !hello world
then: let cmd = arg[1]
```

but also

```
command: !hello world one
then: let cmd = arg[1] + " " + arg[2]
```

I have this, however it only works if `arg[2]` exists, and doesn't if only `arg[1]` is supplied:

```
let cmd = args[1] + " " + args[2];
```

Is there anyway you can specify an arg to pass through spaces? So !hello world one, would be `arg[1] arg[2] (arg[2]` being: world one)

Comment: You seem to be asking two very different questions: (1) how to deal with an optional second argument and (2) how to pass an argument that contains spaces. It's not clear if you're asking the second question as a way of dealing with the first or if it's a separate issue. The first issue can be handled with a ternary expression: `let cmd = arg[2] === undefined ? arg[1] + " " + arg[2] : arg[1];`.

Comment: `let cmd = args.join(" ");` would suffice if you didn't mind them possibly supplying *more* than two arguments.

Comment: Thank you. @TedHopp, how would I go about the second, where args[3] would contain everything from args[3] and onward?

Comment: You can use what @Tyler suggested and collect all remaining arguments with something like `args.slice(3).join(" ")` (which would create a single string containing all elements of `arg` from index 3 onward, separated by a space).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like:

```
const myFunction = (argA, argB) => {
    if (argB === undefined) argB = "";
    console.log(argA + " " + argB);
    return "" + argA + " " + argB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
let test = arg[1] && arg[2] ? arg[1]+' '+arg[1] : arg[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 you can use the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) like so:

```
const myFunction = (...args) => {
 console.log(args[0])   
}
```

if you don't use the fat arrow syntax you can refer to the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) key word:

```
    function func1(a, b, c) {
      if(arguments && arguments.length == 2){
          console.log('do a thing')
        }else{
          console.log('do a different thing')
        }
      };
```